# Perf does not annotate C code called by Rust

Tags: c, rust, perf

I am using `perf` to profile a Rust application which calls some C functions, but I can only find Rust code annotated in the `perf` report.

I have compiled the binaries using debug arguments (`-g`, `-pg` enabled). I run the application as:

```
sudo perf record -pg --call-graph dwarf env RUST_BACKTRACE=full LD_LIBRARY_PATH="<Rust>/lib" ./target/release/<RustApp>
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: Have you annotated your FFI C calls with `#[no_mangle]`? Probably your functions are there but their names are mangled.

Comment: Can you show us a [MCVE] of what you are working on?

Comment: Have you enabled frame pointers/debugging symbols in the compiled c code?

Comment: You probably don't want to use `perf record` on code you compiled with `-pg` because that adds extra asm instructions to instrument the binary.  i.e. to make it record which way branches went.  (At least that's what gcc's `-pg` does.)  This is useful for a later profile-guided optimization build, but you don't want to time a `-pg` build.  You do want `-g`, though.  `-g` adds debug symbols without affecting code-gen.